# How to return multiple parameter with function prototype

Tags: c++, function

The definition is only returning the y param, I am just learning function prototype

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int doDateofBirth(int m , int d , int y);

    int main(){

        cout << "My DoB is, " << doDateofBirth(4,14,1998) << endl;


    }

    int doDateofBirth(int m,int d,int y){
        return m,d,y;
    }
```

Comment: Try reading about the comma operator, more over you might consider creating a `struct` and returning it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't return multiple objects in C++.

```
return m,d,y;
```

That uses the comma operator, which evaluates its left-hand-side expression, throws away its value, then returns the value of the right-hand-side expression. In this case, it's the same as if you had written

```
return y;
```

You could make a class to represent a date, then return that:

```
struct Date {
    //maybe add protection, constructors, methods, etc
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

Date doDateOfBirth (const Date& something);
```

Comment: thanks for this info!

Answer (score 0):

To return as many as you like use : `boost::tuple` for C++ 11 and newer

http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.tuple

Answer (score 0):

In C++, if you want to return multiple variables, consider one of these options:

- Group those variables that you want to return into a struct or a class, depends on how big your object is, and use the struct/class as an parameter inside your program
- Use reference parameters

Based on your example, you could use reference variable option:

Prototype

```
void doDateofBirth(int &m , int &d , &int y);
```

Implementation:

```
void doDateofBirth(int &m,int &d,int &y){
    // do your coding here
}
```

This is how you call the function:
    int month, day, year;
    doDateOfBirth(month, day, year);

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you feel the need to return multiple values, those values actually represent a bigger whole, which you should represent with a distinct datatype containing those values. E.g.:

```
struct DateOfBirth
{
    const int month;
    const int day;
    const int year;
};

DateOfBirth doDateofBirth(int m, int d, int y){
    return { m, d, y };
}
```

And `doDateofBirth` behaves exactly like a constructor here, so we'll make it a constructor:

```
struct DateOfBirth
{
    DateOfBirth(int m, int d, int y) : month(m), day(d), year(y) { } // constructor
    const int month;
    const int day;
    const int year;
};
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
int main()
{
    DateOfBirth mybd(666, 42, 69);
    printf("%d/%d/%d\n", mybd.year, mybd.month, mybd.day);
}
```